# PHP: fopen to create folders

Tags: php, directory, fopen

I need to know if there is any way to create new folder if the path doesn't exist. When I try to fopen() a path, it says `NO such File or Directory exists` I tried to open the file using 'w' and 'w+' but it is not able to create new folder. Is there any way to achieve it without using mkdir(). Because I need to extract the directory names alone from the path to mkdir() everytime.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks...

Answer (score 100, accepted):

fopen cannot create directories.

You'll need to use something like:

```
$filename = '/path/to/some/file.txt';
$dirname = dirname($filename);
if (!is_dir($dirname))
{
    mkdir($dirname, 0755, true);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

fopen doesn't create or open folders, only files. You should check with `is_dir` first if it exists, if not create it. `mkdir` has a recursive create option.

```
if (!is_dir($myDir)) {
    mkdir($myDir, 0777, true); // true for recursive create
}
```

If you are looking for a way to open a dir and read it's content you should look at SPL's [DirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php)

Answer (score 4):

you can't use fopen to create folders.
To create a folder you have to use mkdir

for the operations you have to repeat every time, there is a language feature called "user-defined functions". Least known feature of PHP, as one can say judging by stackoverflow answers.

Comment: > for the operations you have to repeat every time, there is a language feature called "user-defined functions". Least known feature of PHP, as one can say judging by stackoverflow answers: LOL