# error when trying to write file

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite

I am trying to write a file.  I keep getting an error though and I'm not sure what to make of it. Is there anyone who has an suggestions on this.  Thanks so much
The error:

> Warning: fopen(Library/WebServer/Documents/gasDev/test_files/850_855_csv_tests/855_export/GUNB0855.Z9000404): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Library/WebServer/Documents/gasDev/src/controller/containerController.php

this is the function I am using:

```
public function saveFile($saveFile,$content){
    $newFile = fopen($saveFile, 'w');
    fwrite($newFile, $content);
    fclose($newFile);
}//end saveFile()
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant read or write to a directory which doesnt exist. Code in this answer should be run before trying to open it

[PHP: fopen to create folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337854/php-fopen-to-create-folders)