# Failed to open stream: Invalid argument when using PHP fopen()

Tags: php, fopen

Whenever I run some code in PHP, I get these warnings:

> Warning: fopen(extfiles/
>  **Notice**: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\filepath\file.java): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\filepath\file.php on line 82 
>   Warning: feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\filepath\file.php on line 84
>   Warning: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\filepath\file.php on line 87

The lines from the code:

```
$filenamee = $_POST["filename"];
$folder = $_POST["folder"];

$var1 = explode(".", $filenamee);
$var2 = explode(".", $folder);

$filename = "extfiles/".$var2[0]."/".$var1[0].".java";
$file = fopen($filename, "c"); // This is line 82
$lines_array = array();
while (!feof($file)) { // This is line 84


    $line = fgets($file); // This is line 87
    array_push($lines_array, $line);

}
```

The code needs to create and edit Java file, but the problem is that it isn't creating it. Whenever I run this code, I get the last 2 warnings lots of times...

What can I do in order to solve it?

Comment: You should have checked whether the file exists or not using `file_exists()` function. Because the error suggests that the file doesn't exist.

Comment: I know that the file **isn't** exist. I want to create it and write into it

Comment: `fopen` doesn't create directories: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337854/php-fopen-to-create-folders

Comment: But then I still get the 2 last errors, with `string` written instead of `boolean`...

Comment: What do you mean by the word `then`?

Comment: After I change to dirname, I get string instead of boolean

Comment: That means `$file` is a string value which isn't true. `fopen` doesn't return any string value (either resource or false). Be sure to check for possible errors.

Comment: I'm new to PHP, so can you please help me with the code?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the script can not find the file to open. `extfiles/` works from the directory the php file is located in. Can we get a tree view of your dir structure? Typically you'll want to define the entire file path from the root of the drive upward.

Comment: `exfiles` folder is in the same directory as `file.php`.

Comment: if it's in the same directory, why include it? should be like this then: $filename = $var2[0]."/".$var1[0].".java";

Comment: No, it's `filepath/file.php`, and `filepath/extfiles/file.java`.